# How to combine two data frames with date index, current date index of first data frame should get values of next index of second data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames `df1` and `df2` both with date index, how can i combine the two data frames such that, current date index of `df1` should get values of next index of  `df2`.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
a=pd.date_range(datetime(2018,12,31)-timedelta(weeks=54),datetime(2018,12,31),freq='Q')
b =[100,200,300,400,500]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':b},index=a)
a=pd.date_range(datetime(2018,12,31)-timedelta(weeks=90),datetime(2018,12,31),freq='Q')
c= [-1,0,1,2,3,4,5]
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col2':c},index=a)

>>df1 
            col1
2017-12-31   100
2018-03-31   200
2018-06-30   300
2018-09-30   400
2018-12-31   500

>>df2
            col2
2017-06-30    -1
2017-09-30     0
2017-12-31     1
2018-03-31     2
2018-06-30     3
2018-09-30     4
2018-12-31     5
```

is there any way to get an output like below

```
>>df1
            col1  col2
2017-12-31   100     2
2018-03-31   200     3
2018-06-30   300     4
2018-09-30   400     5
2018-12-31   500   NaN
```

i tried merging but it will match indexes an take value from the same index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
pd.concat([df1,df2.shift(-1)],axis=1)
Out[219]: 
            col1  col2
2017-12-31   100   2.0
2018-03-31   200   3.0
2018-06-30   300   4.0
2018-09-30   400   5.0
2018-12-31   500   NaN
```

Comment: @WenBen what if the data frames are of different sizes

Comment: @Shijith `df1.join(df2.shift(-1))
`

Answer (score 1):

Use `join` then `shift`.

```
df = df1.join(df2)
df.col2 = df.col2.shift(-1)

df

            col1  col2
2017-12-31   100   2.0
2018-03-31   200   3.0
2018-06-30   300   4.0
2018-09-30   400   5.0
2018-12-31   500   NaN
```